# Data structure for caching recently computed data

Tags: caching, memory

Question: Is there a data structure for [key,value] entries that has **very** fast look-ups, with limited size, that can throw away entries based on how old they are?

This is needed for the following situation:

- The program is running an optimization where nodes are evaluated.
- Evaluation of the nodes is relatively expensive.
- The optimization reaches the same nodes quite often.
- The re-visiting of nodes has temporal locality (older nodes are less likely to be seen again)
- keys are small sets of values (1 to 10 integers), values a single integer

I want to remember the original evaluation of nodes to speed up the performance.
But not all visited nodes can be stored as that would takes too much memory.